# How to put google slide on Jekyll

Tags: powerpoint, jekyll, slideshow, blogs

Can someone tell me steps to put google shared slides like [this](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1QSGn19Pg7EllzzsLj0pGdZOsEMRkgvgAgvP7YP_UvKQ/edit#slide=id.g1059d87_0_0) on Jekyll my Blog?
Do I have to convert every slide in markdown format or convert in pdf and then in markdown?

No clues. please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To embed a Google Slides presentation in a Jekyll post or page, open the presentation and select “Publish to Web” from the “File” menu.

Choose the options you require, then select the “Embed” tab. You’ll be provided with an embed code. Paste this into your Jekyll post or page - i.e. straight into the markdown file. Generate your site as usual, and the iframe with your presentation will be embedded in the rendered HTML.

This works because when Jekyll parses markdown it also reads any HTML that it finds.

It won’t be responsive out of the box, so you’ll need a bit of CSS. I’ve shown this inline, but you could add the CSS to your stylesheet:

```html
<style>
.responsive-wrap iframe{ max-width: 100%;}
</style>
<div class="responsive-wrap">
<!-- this is the embed code provided by Google -->
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1F0DQTNPg3YG_By6LMGcgwT3icJ3eMhCiupAZm76CIfE/embed?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000" frameborder="0" width="960" height="569" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
<!-- Google embed ends -->
</div>
```

You can see an example on a Jekyll site [here](http://dev-notes.eu/2016/09/embed-google-slides-in-jekyll/).

Comment: this is awesome